# React-Redux - Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," in action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following code:

menu.types.js:

```
export const FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS = "FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS";
```

menu.actions.js:

```
import { apiUrl, apiConfig } from '../../util/api';
import { FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS } from './menu.types';

export const fetchCategoryRanks = menu => async dispatch => {
    console.log("Printing menu (fetch category ranks)");
    console.log(menu);

    menu.map(async (category) {
        const options = {
            ...apiConfig(),
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(category)
        }
        const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/category/${category._id}`, options)
        let data = await response.json()
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("It got sent")
        } else {
            alert(data.error)
        }
    });

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS, menu });

}
```

menu.reducer.js:

```
// import INITIAL_STATE from './menu.data';
import { FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS } from './menu.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = []


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_CATEGORY_RANKS:
           return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

When I run my application, I am getting the following error in the action creator `fetchCategoryRanks`:

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing from this function, as all the curly braces match up with each other. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: async (category) => {

Answer (score 0):

Missing `=>` in map

```
  menu.map(async (category) => {
        const options = {
            ...apiConfig(),
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(category)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Han stated, you're missing `=>` in your map's arrow function:

```js
menu.map(async (category) => {
  const options = {
    ...apiConfig(),
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(category)
  }
  ...
}
```